# How to create 2 (or more) dimentional array in python

Tags: python-2.7

I read that python doesn't have native array data structure. Then I read the library https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html
but can't find how to create 2 dimentional array
How can I create that type of array or are there any ways to replace array in python?

Comment: You could use list of lists. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: Since you said three or more, It is better to go for Numpy array as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448594/how-to-add-elements-to-3-dimensional-array-in-python