# Appending element to a 3-dimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with appending a new element to a 3-dimensional list. Instead of appending a new element in one place (`threeDimList[1][1]`), it appends it in the whole row (`threeDimList[1][0]`, `threeDimList[1][1]`, `threeDimList[1][2]`) Here is my code:

```
threeDimList = [[[]]*(3) for i in range(3)]
threeDimList[1][1].append(1)
print(threeDimList)
```

which gives me:

```
[[[], [], []], [[1], [1], [1]], [[], [], []]]
```

instead of:

```
[[[], [], []], [[], [1], []], [[], [], []]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add elements to 3 dimensional array in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448594/how-to-add-elements-to-3-dimensional-array-in-python)

Comment: Although the question being asked is a duplicate the problem encountered is different.

Comment: @ncfirth we could still relate to the marked duplicate question and the answer provided here is similar the marked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `[[]] * 3` basically creates a list containing three references to the same `[]`.

You can do something like:

```
>>> a = [[] for i in range(3)]
>>> a[0].append(1)
>>> a
[[1], [], []]
>>> b = [[]] * 3
>>> b[0].append(2)
>>> b
[[2], [2], [2]]
```

In the `a` case, given list comprehension, `[]` is evaluated three times, so you get a new empty list object in memory for every evaluation.

In the `b` case, `[]` is evaluated once, wrapped as `[[]]`, and then that is replicated.

Comment: Thanks. So basically the problem was with creating the list. My solution to this problem is as follows: `threeDimList = [[[] for i in range(3)] for i in range(3)]`